# Advanced Custom Fields: checkbox in repeater field

Tags: checkbox, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I can’t seem to get checkboxes working in an Advanced Custom Fields repeater field. The goal is that a different image will be spit out based on what checkbox has been ticked off. The time/title/description part is working great... just need some assistance understanding how to work in the checkbox values.

```
<?php if( have_rows('agenda') ): ?>
  <ul>
    <?php while( have_rows('agenda') ): the_row(); 
        $time = get_sub_field('time');
        $title = get_sub_field('title');
        $description = get_sub_field('description');
        $image = get_sub_field('imagepicker');
    ?>

        <li>
            <h3><?php echo $time; ?><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
            <?php if( $description ): ?>
                <?php echo $description; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( 'option1' == get_sub_field('imagepicker') ): ?>
              <img src="/option1.jpg" />
            <?php elseif ( 'option2' == get_sub_field('imagepicker') ): ?>
              <img src="/option2.jpg" />
            <?php elseif ( 'option3' == get_sub_field('imagepicker') ): ?>
              <img src="/option3.jpg" />
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

(and yes I have gone over the other similar S.O. answers but no luck)

Answer (score 1):

finally figured it out... working snippet below in case anyone else runs into the same thing.

```
<?php if ($image[0] == 'option1') : ?>
  <img src="/option1.jpg" />
<?php elseif ($image[0] == 'option2') : ?>
  <img src="/option2.jpg" />
<?php elseif ($image[0] == 'option3') : ?>
  <img src="/option3.jpg" />
<?php endif; ?>
```